# Facebook School List

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anybody have any ideas on how to query facebook to get a list of the following information.  Preferably using PHP or javascript.

- School Name
- Facebook School ID
- School Address

Is it even possible?

Comment: Is this for a given user or do you want to get a list of every school that one could possibly choose from on Facebook?

Comment: I would like to compile a list of every school that one could possibly choose from on facebook, not just schools that a user has in their profile.

Comment: The College Board sells this data, and I assume Facebook used it as a basis for a list of schools.  You want CEEB Code data and you can request it here: http://professionals.collegeboard.com/data-reports-research/cb/request-for-data

Comment: Interesting, although that only answers half of the question though.  That list has about 65k rows in it how can I go about getting the facebook school ID for each of them?

Comment: I guess the best you could do is match college/high school name since the Facebook ID does not appear to be a CEEB Code.  And if you need school address, College Board looks like the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a users education you first need to ask for the 'user_education_history' permissions, this gives you access to all the schools, colleges and universities that the user has added to their profile. You can also use the 'friends_education_history' permission to get the same information for all of the users friends.

To then get this data from the graph api you make a call to http://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=education to get just the users education data or http://graph.facebook.com/me which includes all the users profile data including education.

This should return an array similar to the below, which includes the school name, Facebook id and type.

```
{
    "school": {
        "id": "114622328554906", 
        "name": "Fakenham High School"
    }, 
      "type": "High School"
    }
}
```

To then get the location/address you can take it's Facebook id and make a call to http://graph.facebook.com/SCHOOLS_FACEBOOK_ID to retrieve all information about it or add ?fields=location to the end of that url to return just the location.

However this does depend on the school actually having location data on Facebook.